# How to loop a formula into a list

Tags: python, list

I am new to coding and my spelling is not the best but I need help with something, I am trying to loop a formula to make a sequence that is stored in a list. Here is my code so far;

```
 for i in range(list):
        number1 = number63*number99
        number2 = number1*number33
        number3 =(number2*number34)+(number64*number35)
        total = number1 + number2 + number3
```

don't worry about the variables they are completely irrelevant as they only make sense to me but i just was to know how i could do this.

Comment: Which variable should be a list? You might want to check the `append()` method for lists.

Comment: Would you add a Simple Input output example please?

Comment: Can't get your question really. Can you give an example what your code should achieve?

Comment: my code should achieve a list that has a sequence generated from my formulas

Comment: perhaps you want to create `answer = []` before your for-loop and then `answer.append(total)` within your loop

Comment: @PortableGibbon should your list grow by 3 numbers each iteration or by just a single number?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
for i in range(list):
        number1 = number63*number99
        number2 = number1*number33
        number3 =(number2*number34)+(number64*number35)
        total += [number1] + [number2] + [number3]
```

This will make `total` a list which adds the three numbers to it each loop iteration

An alternative is to use `extend`:

```
total.extend([number1, number2, number3])
```

Please note that for both of these methods, you need to initialize `total` somewhere earlier in your code, e.g.

```
total = []
```

Additionally, you are using the [`range` function wrong](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/). If you want to iterate the length of a list, do `range(0,len(lst))`. Please also note that using the variable name `list` is ill-advised as it is [a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) in Python.

Comment: I am getting an error about the (list) why is that? All i have done is created a list at the top of the program like this 'list = [ ] "

Comment: @PortableGibbon this is because you are not using the `range` function correctly. I've edited my answer for detail